# Select all rows between two specific times across multiple days

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm managing an SQLite database containing messages along with associated timestamps collected over the past month, and I wish to select all of the entries, for all days, between two given hours.  In pseudocode style: `SELECT * FROM Messages BETWEEN x AND y`, where `x` might be 14:45 and `y` 15:45, and returning all the messages between `x` and `y` for all the days over the past month.

Is there a straightforward way of performing this in SQLite?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM MESSAGES
WHERE time(timestamp) >= time('14:45:00')
  AND time(timestamp) <= time('15:45:00')
```

Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cde2c/1/0

I took information from: http://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=DateAndTimeFunctions