# Presto SQL / Athena: select between times across different days

Tags: sql, date, where-clause, presto, amazon-athena

I have a database that contains a series of events and their timestamp.

I find myself needing to select all events that happen between 11:00 and 11:10 and 21:00 and 21:05, for all days.

So what I would do is I extract from timestamp the hour and the minute, and:

```sql
SELECT *
 WHERE (hour = 11 AND minute <= 10)
    OR (hour = 21 AND minute <= 05)
```

However, I was wondering if there's a simpler / less verbose way to do this, such as when you query between dates:

```sql
SELECT *
 WHERE date BETWEEN '2020-07-01' AND '2020-07-05'
```

I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32365005/select-all-rows-between-two-specific-times-across-multiple-days) that this is doable in SQLite, I was wondering if it's possible to be done in presto as well. I've looked at the docs but couldn't find an analogue function that does what `time()` does in SQLite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use date formatting functions, e.g. [`date_format`](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/functions/datetime.html#date_format), then string comparisons:

```
select *
from mytable
where 
       date_format(mydate, '%H:%i') between '11:00' and '11:09'
    or date_format(mydate, '%H:%i') between '21:00' and '21:04'
```

Note that I substracted one minute from the upper bound, since I assume you don't want to include the last minute. `between '11:00' and '11:09'` gives you everything from `11:00:00` to `11:09:59`.

Comment: If `mydate` is a `TIMESTAMP` you can also do `WHERE CAST(mydate AS TIME) BETWEEN TIME '11:00' AND TIME '11:09'`. It's more or less the same thing, but possibly less work for the query engine.