# Is there a function to select a group of hours from different days?

Tags: datetime, amazon-athena

I'm looking for a way to select in Amazon Athena a selection of hours for different days.
I have a table with visitors to a specific location for every half hour, I now want to know the visitors during opening hours for a store, for the period of a month.

I now used this but doing it day by day is quite a job.
Was trying to split datetime with Datepart but didn't get it working properly.

```
SELECT visitors, datetime
FROM corrected_scanners_per_half_hour
WHERE datetime
    BETWEEN CAST('2020-05-25 08:30:00' AS timestamp)
        AND CAST('2020-05-25 17:30:00' AS timestamp) ;
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Presto SQL / Athena: select between times across different days](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62958313/presto-sql-athena-select-between-times-across-different-days)

Answer (score 0):

Here you go

```
select visitors, date(datetime)
from corrected_scanners_per_half_hour
where date_format(datetime, '%H:%i') between '08:30' and '17:30'
```

Comment: I am assuming column is of timestamp type else you need to first use date_parse then date_format